# How does the "registry-mirrors" setting work in Docker? Is there any authoritative documentation?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to convince the GitHub team at my company to enable a Docker registry mirror by default on our GitHub runners.

<sub>(We have a mirror up and running, but it isn't used by default, which forces every developer to hard-code the full mirror path into our Dockerfiles, which almost nobody remembers to do which leads to constant rate limits.)</sub>

The problem is, I can't find *any* documentation on how this option works, and the GitHub team is nervous about breaking things.

The option is briefly mentioned on these pages:

- https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/mirror/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

But it's missing a lot of crucial detail, like:

- What happens if I configure more than 1 mirror?
- Does order matter? Is the first one preferred, or is load distributed between mirrors, or are they chosen randomly?
- What if we configure 1 mirror and it goes down? Does Docker stop working or does the daemon default back to Dockerhub?

Are there any authoritative answers available for these questions that a poor IT admin can lean on?

Comment: I think the better question would be debugging why the mirror isn't being used in your scenario, rather than asking for a link.

Comment: @BMitch There is no scenario. I'm trying to figure out what *will* happen *if* this configuration is added to every github runner in a very large k8s cluster at my company. I don't think the right approach is YOLO and try to fix it afterwards. Even if I did experiment with this setting and assertain all these answers, the github team at my company would still want authoritative documentation, they wouldn't just trust me. I can't find any documentation at all, so I'm here asking if it exists.